# Convert pandas code to pyspark environment

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i am facing an issue while working on my code in pyspark. I have to convert code from pandas to pyspark.

```
uni_id= df.loc[df['house'], 'student_id'].unique()
class_df= df[df['student_id'].isin(uni_id)]
```

where house column have boolean values - false false true true false true false and so on

student_id are cumsum value like 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 in columns.

df is main-dataframe and class_df will be created from df. I have tried select and groupby method but couldn't able to do that. thanks

Sample output:[image]

Comment: Are you trying to create a dataframe that only has records of the unique `student_id` ? Please show us a sample expected output

Comment: I have given expected output @XXavier

Comment: Why is your output 4 starting from row 12 instead of 3, what is the logic there?